# storing sql in config file

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am using a big nested sql query in python and need to run that query using different dates (date is a field name used in the query).
I also need to change the table name (assume that there are various tables where I need to update the date or insert new records).

Now I am finding it a bit clunky and want to shift the query to config (or .ini) file. I also want to do this so that user can easily change the query without opening the code.

I am able to read the sql but python can't change the variables inside the code.

For example in .ini file the sql is stored as [SQL]:

```
p_insert_query = insert into + tbl_p + <...nested sql>
```

I read this inside python and having the tbl_p already defined as 'My_tbl' in python but the query string is not updating the table name.

Is there any other way to this?

Comment: Are you using psycopg library ?

Answer (score 3):

You could store a .sql or .txt file containing a "parameterized query".

If you use psycopg library you can do it that way (as stated in the doc: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) :

```py
from psycopg2 import sql

my_query_text = "insert into {} values (%s, %s)" # just load that str from .sql or .txt file instead
tbl_p = "my_table_name"

cur.execute(sql.SQL(my_query_text).format(sql.Identifier(tbl_p)), [10, 20]) # [10,20] are sample values
```